Flutter: how to make TextOverflow.ellipse in the middle of Text

I need to create a UI like the image above, but it is not related to the length of the string. It will be limited to the width of the parent Widget that contains it.
I did some reseach and see the same problem here  but there is no answer can resolve my problem
I also found the package extendex_text but it's too heavy to add just for a small problem like this.

I think there isn't any special solution for this you have to create a custom widget for it dividing the text in two chunks and placing the ellipse in between.

You can achieve a similar effect by manipulating the text string like truncate the text and add ellipsis in the middle...calculates how much to truncate from the left and right side of the text and inserts ... in the middle.

Use the below custom widget to achieve the text ellipse in the middle of the string.
class MiddleEllipsisText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;

  const MiddleEllipsisText({super.key, required this.text, this.style});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        // Measure the width of the text
        final textPainter = TextPainter(
          text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
          maxLines: 1,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        )..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);

        if (textPainter.width <= constraints.maxWidth) {
          // Text fits without truncation
          return Text(text, style: style);
        }

        // Calculate the truncation point
        final ellipsis = '...';
        final ellipsisPainter = TextPainter(
          text: TextSpan(text: ellipsis, style: style),
          maxLines: 1,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        )..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);

        final ellipsisWidth = ellipsisPainter.width;
        final availableWidth = constraints.maxWidth - ellipsisWidth;
        final charWidth = textPainter.width / text.length;

        // Determine the number of characters that can fit on each side of the ellipsis
        final charsToShow = (availableWidth / (2 * charWidth)).floor();
        final startText = text.substring(0, charsToShow);
        final endText = text.substring(text.length - charsToShow);

        // Create the final truncated text
        final truncatedText = '$startText$ellipsis$endText';

        return Text(truncatedText, style: style);
      },
    );
  }
}

And use it like below,
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: MiddleEllipsisText(
        text: '0b8931141868658618615312e2a80Ea5f',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
      ),
    )));
  }

Below is the output

